# Additive SNMPd configuration in CentOS

Tags: centos, configuration, snmp, net-snmp

I have a small program that I am preparing for release. As part of its functionality, it queries SNMP for a few statistics.

The MIBs in question are installed by the default `net-snmp` package, but are not enabled by the default `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

I would like to ship a custom configuration file with my RPM, but *I do not want to modify /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf* (in case any of my users have custom configuration in there already).

Is there a way to ship a separate `snmpd.local.conf` file (or something similar) and have it take effect, without modifying `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`? `man snmp_config(5)` seems to imply that it is possible but nothing I try seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are IncludeDir and IncludeFile options available from RHEL/Centos 6.5:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.5_Technical_Notes/net-snmp.html

Comment: Do you know if these are "checked" at all, or are the configuration files just naively concatenated and evaluated by `snmpd`?

Comment: Thanks - ended up adding an `includeDir` to a `snmpd.local.conf` file.